string.contains - no overload for contains takes 2 arguments
I'm trying to use the ignore case option for Contains, and I get this error:
CS1501  No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments 

This is the code line:
item.buildMach.Contains("co.net", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Hovering over Contains, intellisense does say it has 2 overloads, and it looks like it knows it has this second arg.

I'm trying to do what Mathieu Renda has in his solution for this: contains - ignore case
What do I need to do to fix this error and use the ignore case?
This project has target framework of .net framework 4.7.2.
An example that is reproducible:
"str".Contains("sT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Has the error, no overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments.
I'm trying what Mathieu Renda case insensitive contains uses but get this error.

How do we reproduce your issue?

In the link provided, there's a static class called StringExtensions that you'll have to add to your project.

If item.buildMach is a Collection, not a string itself, you can use a LINQ expression to do this

item.buildMach is of type (class) processValidationInfo, the stirng buildMach in the class.

StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is for .Net Core.  You need to be using StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase

I tried changing it to StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase and it still says no overload for method contains takes 2 args

The overload of Contains taking StringComparison was added in .NET Core 2.1 and never ported back to .NET Framework. However it is quite simple to replace it with no lost efficiency:
item.buildMach.IndexOf("co.net", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1

You can also turn it into an extension method:
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return str.IndexOf(value, comparisonType) != -1;
    }
}

Also consider using OrdinalIgnoreCase if  you don't need language-aware comparisons, since it is much faster.

.NET Framework 4.7.2 indeed does not contain (no pun intended) that overload. If you want a case-insensitive comparison in .NET Framework, you could lowercase the string before searching it:
item.buildMach.ToLower().Contains("co.net");


@Michele Don't use ToLower().Contains or ToLower().Equals etc. when you can do the comparison without creating an unnecessary string instance.

I just realized that this makes my comparison fail because co.net sometimes would have uppercase and we're forcing what we are comparing with to be lowercase.

@IS4 - my team wants me to make it so they can have capitalization wrong for  co.net and the comparison will still work. This item.buildMach is from a lengthy list of objects populated using linq so it needs to be an object there.

@Michele Even better a reason to use a method designed for case-insensitive comparison. Please see my answer.

@IS4 - I don't see a posted answer or comment from you

@Michele Strange... does this link work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78618492/1424244

@IS4 your answer appeared. Link works too. Thanks!
